# Unable to type ampersand "&" in Selenium-2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to type the ampersand "&" key in the text-box with selenium web-driver. But selenium-2 looses its focus from type-box while typing the ampersand. My command is, self.type("&", :update => true)

I know that in selenium, keys are sent in UTF_8 format and I have tried to send the equivalent of ampersand but the behavior is still same (as expected). I know XML or HTML supports ampersand with some special escape characters. I want to know is there a way to replace the ampersand with some escape sequence like (HTML code) "&" or "&" in send_keys or type_keys command?

OR is there any other way to type the ampersand "&" in the text-box with selenium-2?

Please let me know your suggestion.

thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours on this over multiple days, and eventually @Asaph told me "temporarily remove all of your javascript and see if that is what is causing the ampersand to blank out."  He was correct. Now `$searchBox->send_keys("bath & body");` works fine.

I eventually narrowed it down to one part of Jquery-ui Autocomplete that was interfering. This property: 
`source:function( request, response ) { //implementation removed }`
All other javascript could remain in place and work fine.  I now want to figure out why Jquery-ui > Autocomplete > Source conflicted with WebDriver and see whether there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), "`&amp;`" is the HTML entity for ampersand. Try it out.

However, I was able to put an ampersand through WebDriver and Java without a problem. Try it on some other input to see whether it's not a local problem...

Comment: I have the same problem as @user1352389, and I too thought that `&amp;` would help, but it didn't. I'm trying: `$searchBox->send_keys("bath &amp; body"); $searchBox->send_keys(WebDriver::ReturnKey());`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by executing JavaScript instead of using the Selenium SendKeys method.

> IJavaScriptExecutor jsExec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
>   jsExec.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('your-input-id-here').value
>   = " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourValueHere));

JsonConvert.SerializeObject() is from JSON.NET, which is a convenient way to encode a string value to be used in JavaScript.  But you could encode your string value in any way that is formatted correctly in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to type "R&d" in a text field, tried below code and it worked.

```
textBox.sendKeys("R/&d")
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I solved it first making it Appium driver from Adroid Driver

Next I switched on Google Keyboard in phone manually which was set appium keyboard
Later I just hid the keyboard and it worked for me.

Thanks anyways for being there.