# How to avoid conflict between Jquery-ui Autocomplete and PHP Selenium WebDriver functional test when typing an ampersand?

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium, webdriver, phpunit

I'm writing a functional test in PHPUnit using Selenium WebDriver.

I need to do this:

`$searchBox->send_keys("bath & body");`
to simulate typing into a text box.

When I run the test, I see it type `bath  body` instead, skipping the ampersand.

I eventually narrowed the problem down to one part of Jquery-ui Autocomplete that was interfering. The [source option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source).

If I temporarily remove the 'source' option, the test runs fine.

All other javascript could remain in place and work fine.

Of course it doesn't make sense to remove the 'source' option; it's required.

Does anyone know what the problem is and whether there is a workaround?

P.S. This question started here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957421/470749

Comment: Does it have anything to do with `&` starting an HTML entity such as `&nbsp;`? Do you need to use `bath &amp; body` instead?

Comment: @DavidHarkness, nope. See the linked question; we already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on java.
Resolved it by define a new String like this:

*String amp = Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "7");*

the code will simulate the key combination <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> avoiding the issue.
Don't know how realize it on PHP, but hope it could be useful to you.